# refreshing table while scrolling ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have tableView with custom cell. I load some information from the internet and add it to the table if user scroll table down. Problem: after loading information new cells sometimes rewrite old cells, and sometimes blank cells appears in this table while scrolling. There is my code:

```
var Bool canEdit = true
@IBOutlet var table : UITableView!
var eventList : [EventCell] = [] // EventCell - custom cell class

func addEventsAndRefresh() {
   if (canEdit){        
       canEdit = false
       HTTPManager.getEvents(isFuture: true, offset: eventList.count, didLoad: getEvents) //it creates url and call function "getEvents" after ending async request
   }    
}

func getEvents(response : NSURLResponse!, data : NSData!, error : NSError!) {
    if ((error) != nil) {
        HTTPManager.showErrorAlert()
    } else {
        var result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray
        for elementOfArray in result {
            var cell : EventCell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventCell") as EventCell
            ... // parsing result to cell
            eventList.append(cell)
            
        }
        table.reloadData()
        canEdit = true
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return eventList.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    return eventList[indexPath.row]
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView!, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    var currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    var maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;
    
    if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= -40.0 && canEdit) {
        addEventsAndRefresh()
    }
}
```

[image: example of blank screen]

Comment: Not sure about this, but my gut feeling is that although the idea of caching your table cells is clever, it might be the reason for your problems. Instead of caching the table view cells just cache the _data_ and create the cells as-needed in `tableView(tableView:, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:)` (as per the usual cell creation pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem when I reused the cell variable as you do.
Try to not put your cells in a list but instead save your result list as an instance variable and get the objects by in index in cellForRowAtIndexPath function as shown below.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
     var cell : EventCell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventCell") as EventCell
     var element = result[indexPath.row] as YourObject
     //Do something with cell
     return cell
}
```